# Retrieve the field values of record in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-data-service, lightning-components

I am using the Lightning Data service in my Lightning Component to update a case record, before I do update the record I need to check on the field value and update accordingly. Below is my component

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global"  >
<aura:attribute name="loaded" type="Boolean" default="false" />
<lightning:spinner variant="brand" alternativeText="Loading..." class="{!(v.loaded? 'slds-show': 'slds-hide')}" />
 <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="form" 
        objectApiName="Case" 
        recordId="{!v.recordId}"
        onsubmit="{!c.handleSubmit}"
        onerror="{!c.handleError}"
        onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}">
        <lightning:inputField aura:id="statusInput" fieldName="Status" class="slds-hide" />
        <lightning:button variant="brand" type="submit" label="Transfer" />
 </lightning:recordEditForm>    
</aura:component>
```

and the controller is like

```
  {
    handleSubmit: function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set('v.loaded',true);
    event.preventDefault();     
    
    var fields = event.getParam('fields');
    var country = fields.Account_Country__c;
    if( country == 'XYZ')
    {
        fields.OwnerId = 'XXXXXXXXXX'; 
    }
    else
    {
        fields.OwnerId = 'YYYYYYYYYYY'; 
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(fields)); 
    component.find('form').submit(fields); 
    $A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();        
},
```

Here the country field is always undefined in the controller I tried even changing the to like below

```
   var country = component.get("v.recordId").Account_Country__c;
```

Even this is not returning the field value associated with the case record.How can I reterieve the field value so I can use them in the controller.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you are missing the `lightning:inputField` for `Account_Country__c`

```
<lightning:inputField aura:id="accountCountryInput" fieldName="Account_Country__c" class="slds-hide" />
```

And you can access it like

```
var fields = event.getParam('fields');
var country = fields.Account_Country__c;
```

Also, the **below code will never work** as it a `recordId`, not the record itself.

```
var country = component.get("v.recordId").Account_Country__c;
```

Comment: I did try that even still I see undefined. Can you Please look in to the screenshot I added now

Comment: @user81642 you are still trying to access it using `component.get("v.recordId")`, which will never work. Try to access it using `fields.Account_Country__c`. See the update.

Comment: I do have that `var country = fields.Account_Country__c;` still undfined

Comment: added screenshot again

Comment: @user81642 please check if the user has sufficient access to the field and check if the field api name is correct. **remember the API name is case sensitive**

Comment: The API name is correct and I am accessing the field as the System Administrator but I double checked I have permissions on the field

Comment: @user81642 are you getting the value of status field?

Comment: It is the same with the Status field if I am accessing in the Controller I see undefined